# Local host says: refuse to connect

Tags: xampp, localhost

I am accessing localhost (XAMPP) on another PC on LAN. It is working fine only if I have no sub folders of my site. For e.g I make folder "android" and paste in htdocs. if android have sub folder it is not working. error is "LOCALHOST REFUSED TO CONNECT". Anyone please tell me what is the problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Have you added an exception for port 80 (and/or 443 if you are using https) to your firewall?

Comment: Maybe your .htaccess file blocks such requests?

Comment: How to unblock such request?

Comment: It depends on your configuration. If you post the contents of your .htaccess, I might be able to help

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

Comment: <IfModule authz_core_module>
  Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>

Comment: Try removing the block with Require all denied (everything that is in your second comment)